# JList with tooltip text in DafaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a JList and each item of the JList has a distinct display text and tooltip text. I would like to use 'DefaultListModel' for the JList. My question is that is it possible to somehow save the tooltip text when added an item to the DefaultListModel.

Thanks.

Comment: Tooltips in JList are defined by the tooltip of the cell `ListCellRenderer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `getToolTipText(...)` method to provide your custom tool tip.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListToolTip extends JFrame
{
    public ListToolTip()
    {
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement("one");
        model.addElement("two");
        model.addElement("three");
        model.addElement("four");
        model.addElement("five");
        model.addElement("six");
        model.addElement("seven");
        model.addElement("eight");
        model.addElement("nine");
        model.addElement("ten");

        JList list = new JList( model )
        {
            public String getToolTipText( MouseEvent e )
            {
                int row = locationToIndex( e.getPoint() );
                Object o = getModel().getElementAt(row);
                return o.toString();
            }

            public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent e)
            {
                int row = locationToIndex( e.getPoint() );
                Rectangle r = getCellBounds(row, row);
                return new Point(r.width, r.y);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( list );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ListToolTip frame = new ListToolTip();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Overriding `getToolTipLocation(...)` is not necessary.

Edit:

> I want to save the custom text in the model

Then you would need to save a custom object in the model that contains the value displayed in the list and the text for the tooltip.

Check out [ComboBox With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for an example of creating an object using this approach.

Comment: I do not want to show the same text as a tooltip for each item. Lets say that I want to show "One apple" for first iem and "two bananas" for second items and so on. And I want to save the custom text in the model.

Comment: @Md.ShahriarMahbub,  `I do not want to show the same text as a tooltip for each item` - obviously, I was just showing you how to use the method. `And I want to save the custom text in the model` - so now you need to modify the logic to get the text of the object you added to the model.

Comment: Overriding toString() method of the class has done the trick.