# Display filename ToolTipText on JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlist, jfilechooser

I have a `JFileChooser`.

I would like it to display a `ToolTipText` (which will be the filename) for each file in the `JList`, when the mouse points over it.

It looks that I will need to override `JList::getToolTipText()`, but I'm having trouble obtaining file chooser's list (and then overriding the `getToolTipText()` method).

I mean, do I have to create a new class that extends a `JLis`t, then override the method in that class, then replace file chooser's `JList` by the new class instance I made?

Do I need to access the `JList ListModel` attribute?

I made some research. These links might be useful:

- [Add ToolTipText in Jlist Item(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098656/add-tooltiptext-in-jlist-items)
- [JList with tooltip text in DafaultListModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161110/jlist-with-tooltip-text-in-dafaultlistmodel)
- [Setting Tool Tip Text for items in a JList Component](https://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/TooltipTextOfList.shtml)
- [How To Add ToolTip On JList Item?](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44036-how-to-add-tooltip-on-jlist-item/)
- [How do I display different tooltip text for each entry in a JList?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=16255)

Comment: You can use the [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class the get the JList component. ` do I have to create a new class that extends a JList, then override the method in that class, then replace JFileChooser's JList by the new class instance I made ?` no, the first link you provided shows you how to add a listener to the JList to set the tool tip text. Or you could also replace the default renderer with a custom renderer. So you could create a wrapper that simply invokes the default renderer, then sets the tool tip text.

Comment: woooooow okk, thank you so much for you advice ! I used a different way to obtain the JList (recursive search with `getComponents()` and `instanceOf JList`). I think your option is more neat.
Also, yes, adding a listener made it !

Comment: *"These links might be useful: .. 
https://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/TooltipTextOfList.shtml"* Wow! I'm surprised anyone *ever* found something useful on the RoseIndia site. It's best avoided.

Comment: hahaha, oops I overlooked this detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolved my problem. Thanks to camickr for helping.

1- Use `SwingUtils getDescendantOfType` to obtain the list

2- Add a mouse listener to display ToolTipText

```
jList.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            JList l = (JList)e.getSource();
            ListModel m = l.getModel();
            int index = l.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            if( index>-1 ) {
                l.setToolTipText(m.getElementAt(index).toString());
            }
        }
    });
```